# Cannot use instance member 'parseData' within property initializer

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this error from the code below. I've read and tried some of the solutions to similar questions but they haven't quite worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class allTripsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let list = parseData()

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func parseData() -> [String] {
    //get some json data and put it into the array
    return delays
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

This works FINE if it's let list = ["Milk", "Honey"] etc. That renders on the table perfectly. But I need it to use the array from parseData instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to make list array allocated as an empty array and then fill it by parsed values?

```
var list = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()

list = parseData()

tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Also it is important to get values from parseData inside the main queue. If you are getting parseData asynchronously, then you have to use completion block inside parseData to return values in the main queue. 
Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No I hadn't tried doing like this. Only one problem, it says "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' "

Comment: Check your code. Maybe you've added that method twice

Comment: Its definitely there only once.
I was thinking it might be to do with how there's 2 functions called tableView but they take in different params...

Comment: Ok. Also I don't remember that this data source  method should be public. Comment that method and try to type it manually. Xcode will propose you correct declaration of it.

Comment: Tried it, no change.

Comment: What's the swift version?

Comment: Go to UITableViewDataSource declaration and copy method from there. Hold cmd and click on UITableViewDataSource

Comment: Swift 3 and yes I got originally got the functions from the datasource declaration

Comment: Just remove "public" then

Comment: @Dharyin did it help you?

Comment: Hey sorry, yeah I think I somehow got it to work, I'm now just hitting an unrelated problem but when I fix that it should work fine, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dharyin that's great. When you'll finish and all will be fine, could you accept my answer please? Thanks in advance